# Expanding absolute div from center to reveal child

Tags: html, css, absolute

I want to have a(n absolutely-positioned) rectangular mask that expands on hover to reveal its (variable height) children. Right now the way that I'm achieving this is with an absolutely positioned div that changes its *left*, *width* and *max-height* values. However, I'd like to make it look like it's expanding from the middle instead of revealing from the top left--and all at the same time.

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="mask">
  <div id="background"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
    #container {
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     background-color: black;
    }

    #mask {
     width: 50px;
     max-height: 50px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 125px;
     left: 125px;
     overflow: hidden;

     transition: width 1s, max-height 1s, left 1s, top 1s;
    }

    #background {
     background-image: url(https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/299-2991041_memes-para-stickers-png-png-download-surprised-pikachu.png);
     background-size: contain;
     width: 150px;
     height: 125px;
    }

    #mask:hover {
     width: 150px;
     max-height: 1000px;
     left: 75px;
     top: 75px;
    }
```

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/jraynolds/pen/OJJxpOm

Comment: You could do something with inset box-shadow instead [like this example](https://codepen.io/misterManSam/pen/wvvrdJY).

Comment: Would it be possible to make the box shadow subtractive, i.e. instead of black in the example it's instead 0 opacity?

Comment: For that you want [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) - ([example here](https://codepen.io/misterManSam/pen/vYYeZEV)) - but there are [current limitations with browser support (IE and Edge) you would have to work around](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_clip-path)

Comment: Thank you! If you'd like to add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### #1 – Using [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

**Compatibility:** [All modern browsers apart from Edge.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_clip-path) IE10/11 and Edge provide limited support using `url()` only.

#### Example with clip-path

To crop the image, use `clip-path: inset()`. In this example, we have a 120 pixel box that is reduced to 0 on hover.

```css
.reveal {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v1Kz.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 150px;
  background-position: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  clip-path: inset(120px 120px 120px 120px);
  transition: clip-path 0.5s;
}

.reveal:hover {
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
}

/*for example*/
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, black 0%, white 100%);
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="reveal"></div>
```

#### Example with url() (not working in Edge or IE)

There was an attempt!

Create an SVG like so:

```
<svg>
    <clipPath id="square">
         <rect />
    </clipPath>
</svg>
```

and place that in the container. The div is given `clip-path: url(#square)` and the width, height, x and y coordinates are provided in the CSS and changed on hover.

```css
.reveal-url {
  background: url(https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/299-2991041_memes-para-stickers-png-png-download-surprised-pikachu.png)
    no-repeat;
  background-size: 150px;
  background-position: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  clip-path: url(#square);
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.reveal-url rect {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  x: 120px;
  y: 120px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}


.reveal-url:hover rect {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  x: 0;
  y: 0;
}

/*for example*/
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, black 0%, white 100%);
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>This only works in Chrome and Firefox.</h1>

<div class="reveal-url">
  <svg>
      <clipPath id="square">
     <rect />
      </clipPath>
  </svg>
</div>
```

### #2 – Using Box-shadow

If you are working with solid background colours, a simple method is to use inset `box-shadow` to mask the contents of the container and then reduce the box shadow on hover.

```css
.reveal {
  background: #000 url(https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/299-2991041_memes-para-stickers-png-png-download-surprised-pikachu.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 150px;
  background-position: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 120px #000;
  transition: box-shadow 1s;
}

.reveal:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 70px #000;
}


/*for example*/

body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="reveal"></div>
```

Comment: Well answered! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works, however, it uses the mask element as a child of the background element, not the other way round.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="background">
    <div id="mask"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You simply give the mask 100% border and zero dimensions and transition to zero border and 100% dimension (transparent). Mask must have elevated z-indez. Like so:

```
#container 
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}
#mask
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-indez: 10;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  border: 150px solid black;
}
#background 
{
  background-image: url(https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/299-2991041_memes-para-stickers-png-png-download-surprised-pikachu.png);
  background-size: contain;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
#background:hover #mask
{
  border: 0 solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here's a pen:
https://codepen.io/jaycodist/full/MWWEpMx

Comment: I'd like the mask (the black in this case) to be the thing expanding, so it wouldn't obscure elements behind it until hovered over.

Comment: Then you simply want to enlarge the mask and reposition it upon mouse hover?